# converting circular structure to json error on simple query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a very simple app that right now allows you to make an account, and just adds a document to a database. When I try to query the information and send it back using `res.send()` it errors and says `converting circular structure to JSON`. What does this mean? All of the objects in the document are strings. There's nothing fancy going on.

Here's the route it's erroring on:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

//  res.send(req.params);
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body.nickname + " from the " + req.body.grade + " class registered.");

  db.collection('users').insert({email: req.body.email, password:     req.body.password, nickname: req.body.nickname, grade: req.body.grade}, function(err, result) {});

  res.cookie("fss-sched-account", req.body.email);
  res.cookie("fss-sched-password", req.body.password);

  console.log(db.collection('users').find({}));

  res.json(db.collection('users').find({}));
});

router.get('/nocookies', function(req, res, next) {
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here's a link to all of my code: [Github](https://github.com/zeekw/FSS-Schedule-Backend)

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are trying to pass the "cursor" from the [`.find()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#find) rather than the "results". You likely just want:

```js
db.collection('users').find({}).toArray(err,results) {
    if (err) throw err; // or handle somehow
    console.log(results);
    res.json(results);
})
```

Where the [`.toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#toArray) converts to an array as well as executing the query, returning a form of data you can actually use.